# How to loop through / return all JSON responses in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Preface: I've spent some time as a light desktop app developer (VBA and SQL - sue me!), but I'm completely new to python.

I'm trying to print the output of a JSON feed in Python as a training exercise:

JSON URL - http://www.nactem.ac.uk/software/acromine/dictionary.py?sf=uk

```json
[
    {
        "lfs": [
            {
                "freq": 656,
                "lf": "United Kingdom",
                "since": 1980,
                "vars": [
                    {
                        "freq": 655,
                        "lf": "United Kingdom",
                        "since": 1980
                    },
                    {
                        "freq": 1,
                        "lf": "United-Kingdom",
                        "since": 2006
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "freq": 393,
                "lf": "urokinase",
                "since": 1969,
                "vars": [
                    {
                        "freq": 358,
                        "lf": "urokinase",
                        "since": 1969
                    },
                    {
                        "freq": 35,
                        "lf": "Urokinase",
                        "since": 1970
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "freq": 6,
                "lf": "uridine kinase",
                "since": 1977,
                "vars": [
                    {
                        "freq": 5,
                        "lf": "uridine kinase",
                        "since": 1977
                    },
                    {
                        "freq": 1,
                        "lf": "Uridine kinase",
                        "since": 2007
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "freq": 6,
                "lf": "urinary kallikrein",
                "since": 1985,
                "vars": [
                    {
                        "freq": 6,
                        "lf": "urinary kallikrein",
                        "since": 1985
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "freq": 4,
                "lf": "urea kinetics",
                "since": 1980,
                "vars": [
                    {
                        "freq": 2,
                        "lf": "urea kinetics",
                        "since": 1980
                    },
                    {
                        "freq": 2,
                        "lf": "urea kinetic",
                        "since": 1989
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "freq": 4,
                "lf": "University of Kentucky",
                "since": 2000,
                "vars": [
                    {
                        "freq": 4,
                        "lf": "University of Kentucky",
                        "since": 2000
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "sf": "UK"
    }
]
```

So far I have only worked out how to return one result at a time using the code below:

```
import urllib.request
import json

def main():

  SearchForAbbrev = input("Please enter an abbreviation to search for:")
  urlData = "http://www.nactem.ac.uk/software/acromine/dictionary.py?sf=" + SearchForAbbrev

  webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(urlData)
  print (webUrl.getcode())
  if (webUrl.getcode() == 200):
    data = webUrl.read()
    data = data.decode("utf-8") 
    printResults(data)

  else:
    print ("Received an error from server, cannot retrieve results " + str(webUrl.getcode()))


def printResults(data):

  theJSON = json.loads(data)

  for i in theJSON:

    print(i["lfs"][0]["lf"])
```

I initially tried using something like `print(i["lfs"]["lf"])` without joy.

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

**Question:** How can I loop through the 0 (index?) value in `print(i["lfs"][0]["lf"])` to return all the results.

For bonus points as a follow up, how do I return all the related results in `vars` too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a closer look at the JSON being output, you have:

1. An array of dicts
2. Within each dict, lfs is an array containing multiple dicts.
3. Inside each of these dicts is a key called vars, which is another array of dicts.
4. It is inside this dict that they key `lf` that you're trying to print can be found.

So, you are simply accessing the JSON data incorrectly. Your print function should be the following:

```
def printResults(data):
    js = json.loads(data)
    for d in js:
        print(d["lfs"][0]["vars"][0]["lf"])
```

Or, if you want to print all `lf`'s:

```
for d in js:
    for e in d["lfs"]:
        for f in e["vars"]:
            print(f["lf"])
```

Comment: Perfect!

I now understand where I was going wrong - I see I'm going to have to pay more attention to the shape of the brackets (curly vs square) with JSON / Python!

Answer (score 0):

Most naturally, looping can be done by... organizing a loop:

```
  for i in theJSON:
    for j in i["lfs"]:
      print(j["lf"])
```

It can also be done a one-liner:

```
print([j["lf"] for j in i["lfs"] for i in theJSON])
```

That was happy path. Checking for invalid input and doing this for `vars` is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I can now see the error of my ways!

If I could mark both your and Ganesh's answers as accepted I would.